# nginx doesn't forward to django app in docker-compose in ubuntu but it all works in docker-machine in Mac

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have a django backend where I use docker-compose to deploy. This django application uses a nginx proxy in the front.

When I deploy it in a docker-machine and I go to the docker-machine ip I am redirected to the django site properly.

But when i deploy it in a ubuntu machine on docker, when i go to the ip of the nginx container I am given the default nginx page, I am not redirected to the django application. The nginx container doesn't log any error too. All services are running in docker without any error.

I am sharing the config file of nginx, docker-compose files below

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name omaha;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.key;

    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 200M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}
```

**nginx dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx
COPY conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
COPY certs/ /etc/nginx/ssl
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx:
      restart: always
      build:
        context: ./nginx/
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      volumes_from:
        - web

    web:
      restart: always
      build:
        context: ./web
      depends_on:
        - web_ffmpeg
        - postgres
        - redis
        - rabbitmq
      expose:
        - "8000"
      environment:
        - DEBUG=True
      command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000


    web_ffmpeg:
      restart: always
      build:
        context: ./web
      depends_on:
        - postgres
        - redis
        - rabbitmq
      expose:
        - "8000"
      command: /usr/local/bin/celery -A trigger worker -l info


    postgres:
      restart: always
      image: postgres:latest
      expose:
        - "5432"
      volumes:
        - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/


    redis:
      restart: always
      image: redis:latest
      expose:
        - "6379"
      volumes:
        - redisdata:/data



    rabbitmq:
      restart: always
      image: rabbitmq:3-management
      environment:
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: 'adminuser'
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: 'xxxxxxxxx'
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: 'myvhost'
      ports:
        - "15672:15672"
      expose:
        - "5672"


volumes:
    elk-data:
    pgdata:
    redisdata:
    web-data:
    web-ffmpeg-data:
```

**software versions:**

I even matched all the version in between the two workstation. The versions are

- docker 1.12.5, 1.13.0
- docker-compose 1.11.0, 1.11.1

I tried all combinations of the versions and still same problem exists.

What is different between using docker-compose in a docker-machine and directly on a ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in gunicorn config.

I didnt bind it to 0.0.0.0:8000 instead I had just binded it to :8000. this was the problem. I still dont know why it worked in machine